# Tailwind CSS shadow on pseudo-element

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Trying to make a shadow that appears behind other elements on the page. I found the solution below which uses a `::before` pseudo-element with a negative z-index to achieve the desired result. (This is along the same lines as multiple other solutions I came across.) However, when I try to implement it with tailwind, the shadow simply doesn't show up. See what I mean below.

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 m-10">
  <div class="bg-yellow-100 before-shadow">1</div>
  <div class="bg-yellow-100 before-shadow">2</div>
  <div class="bg-yellow-100 before-shadow">3</div>
</div>
```

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .before-shadow {
    position: relative;
  }
  .before-shadow::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    @apply drop-shadow-2xl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)